# Create Istio Ingress-gateway POD without creating istiod

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I am bit new to istio and still learning. I have a use-case in which Istio is already deployed in istio-system namespace but I need to deploy istio ingress-gateway Pod in test-ns namespace using istioOperator. I am using istio 1.6.7.

From Istio docs, its mentioned to run this cmd:
`istioctl manifest apply --set profile=default --filename=istio-ingress-values.yaml` but this will create istiod Pods in istio-system which i donot want since its already created.

So, I ran below cmds to just create Ingress Gateway POD but can;t see any Pods or services created in test-ns. Kindly help if this is possible

```
kubectl apply -f istio-ingress-values.yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
    namespace: test-ns
    name: testoperator
    ingressGateways:
    - enabled: true
      name: istio-ingressgateway
      namespace: test-ns
      k8s:
        env:
        - name: ISTIO_META_ROUTER_MODE
          value: sni-dnat
        hpaSpec:
          maxReplicas: 5
          metrics:
          - resource:
              name: cpu
              targetAverageUtilization: 80
            type: Resource
          minReplicas: 1
          scaleTargetRef:
            apiVersion: apps/v1
            kind: Deployment
            name: istio-ingressgateway
        resources: {}
        service:
          ports:
          - name: http2
            port: 80
            targetPort: 80
          - name: https
            port: 443
            targetPort: 443
```

Comment: Is it totally necessary to create the ingressgateway in another namespace? I would suggest you to create the ingressgateway in istio-system namespace, create the gateway also in istio-system and then select the gateway from the virtual service in test-ns namespace.
This way you can have your control plane in the same namespace, and the app that you want to expose in another namespace (data plane).

Comment: How did you install istio ?
Which [configuration profile](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/) are you using ?

Comment: @matt_j, I used this cmd "istioctl manifest apply --set profile=default"

Comment: @ArnauSenserrich, thanks for the suggestion. i tried that but still no success

Comment: Istio-ingressgateway is one singly Envoy proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Istio it is possible to tune [configuration profiles](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/).
As I can see, you are using the `default` profile, so I will describe how you can tune this configuration profile to create `istio-ingressgateway` in the `test-ns` namespace.

---

We can display the default profile settings by running the `istioctl profile dump default` command.

First, I saved these default settings in the `default_profile_dump.yml` file:

```
# istioctl profile dump default > default_profile_dump.yml
```

And then I modified this file:
**NOTE:** I only added one line: `namespace: test-ns`.

```
...
    ingressGateways:
    - enabled: true
      name: istio-ingressgateway
      namespace: test-ns
...
```

After modifying default settings of the `ingressGateways`, I applied these new settings:

```
# istioctl manifest apply -f default_profile_dump.yml 
This will install the Istio 1.9.1 default profile with ["Istio core" "Istiod" "Ingress gateways"] components into the cluster. Proceed? (y/N) y
✔ Istio core installed                                                                                                                                   
✔ Istiod installed                                                                                                                                       
✔ Ingress gateways installed                                                                                                                             
- Pruning removed resources                                                                                                                                Removed HorizontalPodAutoscaler:istio-system:istio-ingressgateway.
  Removed PodDisruptionBudget:istio-system:istio-ingressgateway.
  Removed Deployment:istio-system:istio-ingressgateway.
  Removed Service:istio-system:istio-ingressgateway.
  Removed ServiceAccount:istio-system:istio-ingressgateway-service-account.
  Removed RoleBinding:istio-system:istio-ingressgateway-sds.
  Removed Role:istio-system:istio-ingressgateway-sds.
✔ Installation complete
```

Finally, we can check where `istio-ingressgateway` was deployed:

```
# kubectl get pod -A | grep ingressgateway
test-ns        istio-ingressgateway-7fc7c7c-r92tw         1/1     Running   0          33s
```

The `istiod` Deployment remained intact in the `istio-system` namespace:

```
# kubectl get deploy,pods -n istio-system
NAME                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/istiod   1/1     1            1           51m

NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/istiod-64675984c5-xl97n   1/1     Running   0          51m
```

Comment: Thanks @matt_j. Good suggestions. I will try this

Comment: Hi @matt_j, 1 quick question. If the ingress-gateway is in "istio-system" namespace . And VirtualService and Gateways are created in a different namespace. Does Ingress-gateway scans "Gateways and VirtualService configuration" of all the namespaces defined in the cluster to decide which is the correct gateways/VS to choose